# What is the meaning of the tilde use in this probability expression?

Tags: probability, distributions, notation

$$X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$
$$Y|X = x \sim \mathcal{N}(x,1)$$

I'm familiar with the normal use of tilde in indicating a random variable follows a distribution (such as in the first line of the attached image), but I haven't run into the tilde as it is used in the second line of the attached image. Is this saying that the random variable is *itself* the mean? That doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notation means that the distribution of $Y$ conditioned on the event $X=x$ is $\mathcal N(x,1)$.

It is the same as saying $Y|X\sim\mathcal N(X,1)$, although maybe in proper notation: you condition on the *event* $X=x$ and then use the real number (not random variable) $x$ as the mean for the conditional distribution.

Comment: I think it's helpful if you use parentheses: $(Y|X=x) \sim \mathcal{N}(X, 1)$

Comment: @shadowtalker This is what I was looking for! Thanks, this makes much more sense.